# Device token not coming for iOS 9 device while integrating iOS native push notification with WorkLight

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, worklight-server

I am trying to send Push notification on iOS device via Worklight using sample code and steps provided at https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/notifications/push-notifications-native-ios-applications/

When I run the app on iOS 7 device, i get a device token and therefore when i tap on subscribe button, i get a successful response. This works even if, when we don't write any code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for registeringForRemoteNotifications.

But When i run the same code on iOS 8 and iOS 9 device I am getting following message on console :

**iOSNativePush[1119:372642] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.**

To make my application run for iOS>=8 device, I wrote following code :

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
 {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
   {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:  [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
else
   {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |    UIUserNotificationTypeSound)];
   }
return YES;
   }


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Still i am getting "**iOSNativePush[1119:372642] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later**" message in console but for **iOS 8** device I am getting device token and device is getting subscribed but same thing is not working for **iOS 9** device.

I refered following link also but no luck
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding-and-setting-up-push-notifications-in-development-evnironment?lang=en

Kindly help me to obtain device token for iOS 9 device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

> Use above code

Comment: Thanks for reply, i don't know how but my old code is working today, i got device token for iOS 9 :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in later iFixes of MobileFirst 6.3 and higher.

To resolve:

1) Update your MobileFirst studio to the latest iFix .

2) Add a new iOS native environment.

3) Replace the sample's native folder with the newly generated one ( with iFix)

4) Clean , build and deploy.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.